# Invalid schema configuration error with Mongoose in NestJS application

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am working on an e-commerce application using NestJS and MongoDB (with Mongoose). I have been encountering an error when trying to implement a user's shopping cart in the application. The error message I'm getting is error:

> Invalid schema configuration: 'User' is not a valid type at path 'User'.

Here is the related code snippet from `user.model.ts`:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';

export enum UserRole {
  User = 'User',
  Admin = 'Admin',
}

@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
  ...
  
  @Prop([
    { product: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }, quantity: Number },
  ])
  cart: { product: Types.ObjectId; quantity: number }[];
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
export type UserDocument = User & Document;
```

This is the code from `product.model.ts`:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema()
export class Product extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  description: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  price: number;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  quantity: number;

  @Prop()
  imageUrl: string;
}

export const ProductSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Product);
export type ProductDocument = Product & Document;
```

And here's how I'm importing them in `app.module.ts`:

```
...
import { User, UserSchema } from './models/user.model';
import { Product, ProductSchema } from './models/product.model';
...

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: User.name, schema: UserSchema },
      { name: Product.name, schema: ProductSchema },
      ...
    ]),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've tried various solutions suggested in related questions, such as modifying the way I define the ObjectId in the schema or rechecking the way I define and import the schemas. However, none of these have resolved the issue.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

- NestJS version: 9.0.0
- @nestjs/mongoose version: 9.2.2
- Mongoose version: 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I have run into the same issue, it was because of the type objectId.
try with the `objectId` type of `Schema` types instead:

```js
import { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';
//..
@Prop([
  { product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }, quantity: Number },
])
cart: { product: Schema.Types.ObjectId; quantity: number }[];
```

They are not the same thing, `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` is the correct type when you want to defined a schema.